# FBSDKAppInviteDialog invite successfully sent, but no notifications received

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-invite-friends

#### What I'm doing?

I'm trying to send invitation to my Facebook friends using `FBSDKShareKit`.

#### Is it working?

YES – but only with test users (and not with real users).

#### What's the problem?

1. Getting push notification for the invitation
2. Getting notification inside Facebook app
3. Able to see invitation
4. If app installed then Facebook will redirect to app else will open AppStore for Installation.

These all working fine – but only with test users and not with real users accounts.

#### Some facts :

1. My Facebook app is live and publicly available.
2. The app I'm trying to invite for is not live yet. So I'm using an app id of other app. However this is working (as I've explained above).
3. With real user accounts its working – showing success once I invite to other users, but they will never receive push and inside app notification about that invitation.

#### Your suggestions ?

- As you know this is something really strange ! Its working with test users and not with real users, what I'm doing wrong?
- Any thing that I'm missing?
- How do I make sure that it'll surely work with real accounts when my app will go live!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to my question I got while writing the question, as I've written it too long, I decided to keep it here and give a  answer.

I was not getting push/notifications for real users as I'm trying to invite the users who've already authorised my app. As it require for those real users to remove my app from their Facebook's Settings **[Settings > Apps]** and then if I'll send him a request they will get it.